# Printing the contents of a php array

Tags: php, debugging

I am trying to print or echo out the contents of the GET and POST arrays. I am doing this for debugging reasons as I need to check exactly what is being passed to my submit form.

I am currently using the following code, but nothing is being displayed even though I can see some GET data in the url of the page.

```
<php print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET); ?>
```

On submit I get the following in the url, so the data is going somewhere :

```
&token=3dce374d23c82eaadc8463bc477a418b5ed2dfa2&name=Mrs Newton&date=27-01-2012&chronoform=addupdatelead&event=submit
```

Comment: I hope the '<php' is just a typo in your post...

Comment: is it submitting to the page that has the `print_r`?

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter or any other framework? Those can clean up `_GET` ...

Comment: Why the downvote ?, I was using notepad instead of my usual Dreamweaver so didn't see the problem, iv only been writing php for a few weeks :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need a question mark before php

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<?php print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print_r` or `var_dump` to print out the array as you are doing.  If you do not see any data in them then you are not getting data.

Answer (score 0):

Something helpful to add to the other answers is that throwing a pre tag in will greatly improve the readability of the output.  It will output this way in the source code as well, but sometimes it is nice to just look at it in-page.

```
<pre>
  <?php print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET); ?>
</pre>
```